# How to prevent another event listener (mouseout) after click event has fired in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to disable the `(mouseout)` event once only when `(click)` event has fired.

```html
<li
  class="ci-inline-flex ci-flt-l width100 tooltip ci-cursor"
  *ngFor="let menu of menuData;let i=index"
  [ngClass]="{
            'ci-bgclr-18 ci-border-radius-5': selectedItem == i,
            'disabled': disabledVal == i,
            'disabled': headerdisplay == false && menu.menuName == 'Encounter'}"
  (click)="reDirectTo(menu.route,menu.routeTyPe, menu.menuName,i,$event)"
  (mouseover)="menu.src = menu.activeIcon"
  (mouseout)="menu.src = menu.icon"
>
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hello Shirish, welcome to Stackoverflow. I have improved the English sentences and I have added newlines to your HTML code to make it easier for readers to understand what you are trying to achieve. Please check that I did not make a mistake. Please also consider simplifying your HTML code by removing the parts that are not relevant for your question. I guess the class, *ngFor, [ngClass] and (mouseover) attributes are not relevant?

Comment: I want change Img url on hover for Menu Bar Icons ,I did it but If I click on any menu and moving cursor from that selected menu then (mouseout) event is fire. So, want to prevents mouseout event only after click is fire.

Answer (score 1):

In function `reDirectTo`, you could set a flag, e.g. `redirected = true` and then check that flag in `(mouseout)`:

```
(mouseout)="if (!redirected) menu.src = menu.icon"
```

Comment: Its not working for me any other solution?

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. What happens? Are you unable to set redirected to true, or is menu.src = menu.icon executed even though redirected is true?